# Twig+Wordpress how to use array arguments inside a function?

Tags: php, theme-development, templates

I already asked this on stack overflow but then I found this place.

I've searched but didn't find any answer to this.

I'm using a theme that was developed using the Twig template system. I don't know anything about Twig and I don't have the time to learn it.

In wordpress we can use `get_terms()` to get all the terms from a taxonomy but we can "filter" the terms we want to receive using an array of arguments that is the second parameter to the function.

That being said, I have a line in a twig file that goes like this:

```
{% for distrito in wp.get_terms('Distritos') %}
```

`distrito` is my variable and `Distritos` is my taxonomy name. This works, it calls all of the terms, but I want to use the array arguments so that I can get only the root elements since my taxonomy is hierarchical.

I understand that I must have somewhere the place where `wp.get_terms` is defined but I can't find it and I've been around this for 2 days now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is straight pass through to native WP function this *might* work:

```
{% for distrito in wp.get_terms('Distritos', {'foo': 'bar'} ) %}
```

However overall this is specific to implementation and is hard to guess without taking that code apart.